# Why my reorder is not working in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to sort my `bar chart` using `reorder` but, it is not working. I am getting the bar as `unsorted` format.

The code I am using,

```
ggplot(Top_SP_NB_Precison_Avg_long) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(Top_Percision, -Top_Value), y = Top_Value, fill=Model_Name), position=position_dodge(width=1), stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(Top_Percision, Top_Value, label=round(Top_Value, digits = 2), group=Model_Name), position=position_dodge(width=1), size=4)+
  facet_grid( ~ Dataset_Number,
              labeller = labeller(Dataset_Number = function(x)paste0("Test Dataset ",x))) + 
  ggtitle("Percentage of Top 1, Top 2, and Top 5 for (Dataset 1: Disjoint and Dataset 2: Joint)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The plot I am getting

[image]

I want to `sort` the bar chart based on the `Top_Values`. After using the `reorder` I am getting `reorder(Top_Percision, -Top_Value)` in my figure but I want to show only `Top_Precision`. Moreover, I want to add the `Model_Name and Top_Precision` in the bar (horizontally)`. Because the values are getting overwritten one after another.

Reproduciable Code:

```
 structure(list(Model_Name = c("AA", "AA", "CN", "CN", "Dice", 
"Dice", "JAC", "JAC", "L3", "L3", "RA", "RA", "SP_2", "SP_2", 
"SP_3", "SP_3", "AA", "AA", "CN", "CN", "Dice", "Dice", "JAC", 
"JAC", "L3", "L3", "RA", "RA", "SP_2", "SP_2", "SP_3", "SP_3", 
"AA", "AA", "CN", "CN", "Dice", "Dice", "JAC", "JAC", "L3", "L3", 
"RA", "RA", "SP_2", "SP_2", "SP_3", "SP_3"), Dataset_Number = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("dataset_1", 
"dataset_2"), class = "factor"), Top_1_Number_1 = c(968.2, 1103.4, 
968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 
1103.4, 49.7333333333333, 168.16577540107, 23.1891891891892, 
278.5, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 
968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 49.7333333333333, 168.16577540107, 
23.1891891891892, 278.5, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 
1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 968.2, 1103.4, 49.7333333333333, 
168.16577540107, 23.1891891891892, 278.5), Top_2_Number_1 = c(1936.6, 
2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 
2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 100.144444444444, 336.540106951872, 47, 
557.7, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 
2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 100.144444444444, 336.540106951872, 
47, 557.7, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 
2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 1936.6, 2207.4, 100.144444444444, 336.540106951872, 
47, 557.7), Top_5_Number_1 = c(4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 
4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 
251.122222222222, 841.545454545455, 118.175675675676, 1394.8, 
4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 
4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 251.122222222222, 841.545454545455, 
118.175675675676, 1394.8, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 
5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 4841.9, 5519.6, 251.122222222222, 
841.545454545455, 118.175675675676, 1394.8), Top_Percision = c("Top_1", 
"Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", 
"Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", "Top_1", 
"Top_1", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", 
"Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", 
"Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_2", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", 
"Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", 
"Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5", "Top_5"), Top_Value = c(0.562825438620055, 
0.666442239087732, 0.527325534968645, 0.646535342402335, 0.395479141226974, 
0.594138479126739, 0.395479141226974, 0.594138479126739, 0.575402174648061, 
0.313552087504645, 0.636320734135852, 0.70882815479768, 0.836930861233382, 
0.225230231229633, 0.0511163337250294, 0.00110342848845767, 0.356378424218613, 
0.368592532979545, 0.331746900931854, 0.35800341437544, 0.309550233556993, 
0.350144576861987, 0.309550233556993, 0.350144576861987, 0.416685970371373, 
0.392537436373919, 0.395005999891646, 0.38587835397129, 0.604172142037466, 
0.151509806996773, 0.0325980177679993, 0.00145325630169788, 0.174284724341723, 
0.159738121683694, 0.171757392425061, 0.157253225028994, 0.173476420027052, 
0.159230629844388, 0.173476420027052, 0.159230629844388, 0.172942924490357, 
0.15904978122944, 0.174328632135356, 0.159738121683694, 0.395331576314268, 
0.0906560167264891, 0.0225437625433477, 0.00086710964578538)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), groups = structure(list(Model_Name = c("AA", "CN", "Dice", 
"JAC", "L3", "RA", "SP_2", "SP_3"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 
2L, 17L, 18L, 33L, 34L), c(3L, 4L, 19L, 20L, 35L, 36L), c(5L, 
6L, 21L, 22L, 37L, 38L), c(7L, 8L, 23L, 24L, 39L, 40L), c(9L, 
10L, 25L, 26L, 41L, 42L), c(11L, 12L, 27L, 28L, 43L, 44L), c(13L, 
14L, 29L, 30L, 45L, 46L), c(15L, 16L, 31L, 32L, 47L, 48L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You're going to have a problem here mostly because you're ordering will change for each grouping/pairing of `Top_Percison` and `Dataset_Number`.  By this I mean "SP_2" Model is highest in Top_1 in Dataset_1, but not in dataset_2 = where it's lowest.  "L3" changes positions in most pairings... so no mater what it's not going to work out when you order this way.  Any other way of showing what you need?

Comment: Why did you delete the `swap` question??

Comment: I found the solution, so I thought, I should not keep the question. May I made any mistakes? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reorder()` function used in that way sees the entire dataset at once, whereas I suspect you want to reorder the model names within the x-position in every facet. To do this, you can use the `interaction()` function with the grouping variables to quickly form subgroups.

```r
df <- transform(
  Top_SP_NB_Precison_Avg_long,
  group = reorder(interaction(Top_Percision, Model_Name, Dataset_Number), 
                  -Top_Value)
)
```

The only adjustment you'd have to make while plotting is setting the groups correctly in every geom. Also, I had assumed you meant to say 'vertically' instead of 'horizontally' for text orientation, as I couldn't figure out how leaving the text horizontal would lead to clearer labelling.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(
    aes(x = Top_Percision,
        y = Top_Value, 
        fill= Model_Name,
        group = group), 
    position=position_dodge(width=1)
  ) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(Top_Percision, 
        Top_Value, label=paste0(Model_Name, ": ", round(Top_Value, digits = 2)), 
        group= group), 
    position=position_dodge(width=1), size=3, angle = 90, hjust = 1
  )+
  facet_grid( ~ Dataset_Number,
              labeller = labeller(Dataset_Number = function(x)paste0("Test Dataset ",x))) + 
  ggtitle("Percentage of Top 1, Top 2, and Top 5 for (Dataset 1: Disjoint and Dataset 2: Joint)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your code. The `SP_3` is not showing the full name. Maybe this is for the very low value. But, is it possible to show `SP_3` a little up in the figure?

Comment: Yeah in the text geom use `pmin(Top_Value, 0.1)` instead of `Top_Value` for the y-aesthetic. Replace the 0.1 with whatever looks best.